# How can one manipulate an equation within variance?

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

I encountered the following equation to find the variance of, given that $V(\hat\theta_1)=\sigma^2_1$,and $V(\hat\theta_2)=\sigma^2_2$.

I considered that for the variance of $\mathcal F=\alpha\hat\theta_1+(1-\alpha)\hat\theta_2$:
$$V(\mathcal F)=V(\alpha\hat\theta_1+(1-\alpha)\hat\theta_2)=V(\alpha\hat\theta_1+\hat\theta_2-\alpha\hat\theta_2)=\alpha^2V(\hat\theta_1)+V(\hat\theta_2)+\alpha^2V(\hat\theta_2)=\alpha^2\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2+\alpha^2\sigma^2_2$$

The professor considered:
$$V(\mathcal F)=\alpha^2\sigma^2_1+(1-\alpha)^2\sigma^2_2\color{red}{\stackrel{\mathtt{expansion}}{=}\alpha^2\sigma^2_1+(1-2\alpha+\alpha^2)\sigma^2_2=\alpha^2\sigma^2_1+\sigma^2_2-2\alpha\sigma^2_2+\alpha^2\sigma^2_2}$$

I do not see how these two statements are equivalent, presuming both ways are correct in the application of the variance properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$V(\mathcal F)=V(\alpha\hat\theta_1+(1-\alpha)\hat\theta_2)=V(\alpha\hat\theta_1+\hat\theta_2-\alpha\hat\theta_2)\color{red} \neq\alpha^2V(\hat\theta_1)+V(\hat\theta_2)+\alpha^2V(\hat\theta_2)$$

Could you see the reason? $\hat\theta_2$ and $\alpha\hat\theta_2$ are not uncorrelated.

Please see [Basic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance) of Variance. In particular, check the formula for $$\text{Var} \left(\sum_{i=1}^N a_i X_i \right)$$

Comment: What do you mean by not uncorrelated? I used the property that $V(aX+b)=a^2V(X)$.

Comment: Thanks @PTDS for the help